# showpare 6 app how to get user timezone in iframe

Tags: shopware6-app

I want to get user timezone to format datetime in the iframe but Admin Extension SDK does not have it so far.

currently, we can get user locale https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/context#locale

Is there any way to get timezone in iframe?

This timezone is saved in user profile, not browser timezone
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so far, it's impossible. I just workaround to get timezone of client by javascript